# How to get max value AND respective column name with pandas dataframe where column names start with specific strings

Tags: python, dataframe, max, multiple-columns

I have a df that looks something like this, but with a lot of more columns of each feature (colour, brand, type, size etc)
This is the score customer gave to colour, brand, type etc.

| customer | colour_green | colour_blue | colour_red | brand_a | brand_b | brand_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cust_1 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 6 | 2 | 2 |
| cust_2 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| cust_3 | 7 | 3 | 5 | 2 | 5 | 10 |

For every customer I would like to create additional columns which is the highest scoring colour for that customer , highest scoring brand etc..
Challenge is there are many columns starting with 'colour_...', 'brand_...' and hence I wish to use max argument where column starts with ('colour_') or max('brand'_)

I have tried

```
i = df.columns.str.contains(r'colour_\s+\d+\s+')
j = df.columns.str.contains(r'brand_\s+\d+\s+')
```

but I get error 'can only use .str accessor with index, not multiindex'.

also tried

```
mask = df.columns.str.contains('colour_.*')

df.loc[:,mask] # selects mask
```

but I get error:AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with Index, not MultiIndex

I can not apply this

```
df.apply(pd.Series.idxmax, axis=1)
```

as I want to find max(based on certain columns like  colour related for colour , brand related for brand)

Hence I assume wild card like above is essential.

I am expecting output where without explicitly mentioning all colour column names and brand names,
I should get  colour name which has max colour score and brand name which has max (brand scored) as output in front of that customer.

| cust | clr_green | clr_blue | clr_red | brd_a | brd_b | brd_c | max_clr | max_brd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cust_1 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 6 | 2 | 2 | blue | a |
| cust_2 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 2 | red | a,b |
| cust_3 | 7 | 3 | 5 | 2 | 5 | 10 | green | c |

Answer (score 0):

Well, this isn't that pretty, but it works. `idxmax` isn't gonna work for you, as you want every item that matches the max, not just the first.

We'll first generate the fake dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

np.random.seed(0)


def gen_properties(name):
    return {name + '_' + chr(i+ord('a')): np.random.choice(10, size=10) for i in range(3)}


df = pd.DataFrame({'customer': range(10), **gen_properties('color'), **gen_properties('brand')})
print(df)
```

Then select columns that max the match in each row, having filtered by item type.

```
def max_by_type(frame, item):
    filtered_frame = frame[[i for i in frame if i.startswith(item)]]
    maxes = filtered_frame.max(axis=1).values.reshape(-1, 1) == filtered_frame
    return [','.join(value[len(item):] for value in maxes.columns[row[1]].values) for row in maxes.iterrows()]


df['maxcolor'] = max_by_type(df, 'color_')
df['maxbrand'] = max_by_type(df, 'brand_')
print("******")
print(df)
```

This will yield:

```
   customer  color_a  color_b  color_c  brand_a  brand_b  brand_c
0         0        5        7        5        2        9        0
1         1        0        6        9        3        9        4
2         2        3        8        8        8        0        5
3         3        3        8        9        1        4        5
4         4        7        1        4        3        7        6
5         5        9        6        3        3        3        8
6         6        3        7        0        3        2        4
7         7        5        7        3        7        7        1
8         8        2        8        5        0        2        4
9         9        4        1        0        1        0        9
******
   customer  color_a  color_b  color_c  brand_a  brand_b  brand_c maxcolor maxbrand
0         0        5        7        5        2        9        0        b        b
1         1        0        6        9        3        9        4        c        b
2         2        3        8        8        8        0        5      b,c        a
3         3        3        8        9        1        4        5        c        c
4         4        7        1        4        3        7        6        a        b
5         5        9        6        3        3        3        8        a        c
6         6        3        7        0        3        2        4        b        c
7         7        5        7        3        7        7        1        b      a,b
8         8        2        8        5        0        2        4        b        c
9         9        4        1        0        1        0        9        a        c
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution and when I run your code it works well. The error that I am getting is  -'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'. I will figure out what is the issue. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html#pandas-dataframe-filter):

```py
def get_max(df, col):
    f = df.filter(like=f'{col}_')
    m = f.max(axis=1)
    return f.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(c.split('_', maxsplit=1)[-1] for c in x.index[x == m[x.name]]), axis=1)

df['max_brand'] = get_max(df, 'brand')
df['max_colour'] = get_max(df, 'colour')

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  customer  colour_green  colour_blue  colour_red  brand_a  brand_b  brand_c max_brand max_colour
0   cust_1             2            5           3        6        2        2         a       blue
1   cust_2             1            3           4        3        3        2      a, b        red
2   cust_3             7            3           5        2        5       10         c      green
```

Comment: thank you for the solution . It works well. The error that I am getting is ' index 774 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 774'. and I am sure it is not related the solution you have provided. My df is 451350X 1650 shape and may be that is somewhere posing a problem.

Comment: @python_new Do you have columns with duplicate names?

Comment: no column names are not duplicate. But they are similar , like ' 'colour_affinity_green', 'colour_socre_green'  and therefore I have made necessary changes  in df['max_colour'] = get_max(df, 'colour_affinity_')...to find max of all columns start with (colour_affinity_)

Comment: @python_new The change `c.split('_')[-1]` to `c.split('_', maxsplit=1)[-1]`